# How Long Does It Take For A Google Maps API Key To Become Active?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How long does it take for a new Google Maps API key take to become active? I have just added a new key and a new package to an existing key, but neither seem to work. Is it an issue with the key getting activated?

Comment: do you got any error in logCat, because `Google Maps API key` becomes active as soon as you generate key.

Comment: Uninstall your application and re-install in newly. It'll works correctly.

Comment: The errors are about an invalid key, although I have checked and double checked the keys, SHA1's, package names, everything. They're all correct.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ it helps to setup with map. once again check it

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the api access to all the services you need
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: Already done, considering it works when using the debug key but not using the release key

Answer (score 0):

The key is active as soon as you generate it.

1. On the first time, you should run the signed apk on a real device and not while plugged in to your eclipse.
2. Notice that the SH1 of your app is shown when you sign your apk.
3. for diffrent apps, the only thing that worked for me was to open new projects for each app ang get a key separately.

Good luck